# Manifest merger failed : Android studio multiple errors

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I woke up happy to continue to develop my app but, i faced with an error which i do not know how to solve this bullsh ** i just woke up and the build show me various errors :'( i'm sad please help me

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:5-77:19 to override.
```

**MY MERGED MANIFEST**

```
Merging Errors: Error: Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:5-77:19 to override. app main manifest (this file), line
```

**MY ANDROID MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.service.NanoDigital">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DIContrato"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MarcaContrato"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MarcaContratoUsoDeImagem"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DILoginInstagram"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeInstagramlogin" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MarcaLoginInstagram"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeInstagramlogin" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />


    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DIApiInstagram" />
    <activity android:name=".MarcaApiInstagram" />
    <activity android:name=".MarcaAprovacao" />
    <activity android:name=".DIAprovacao" />
    <activity android:name=".MarcaPlanos" />
    <activity android:name=".DIPlanos" />
    <activity android:name=".DIPlanoMensal" />
    <activity android:name=".DIPlanoTrimestral" />
    <activity android:name=".DIPlanoSemestral" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MarcaPopupMensage"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".DITags" />
    <activity android:name=".plano_cor_mes_ano" />
    <activity android:name=".MarcaServicoProduto" />
    <activity android:name=".marca_servico_produtoTags" />
    <activity android:name=".Marca_Produto" />
    <activity android:name=".Marca_Servico" />
    <activity android:name=".MarcaTagServicoLayout" />
    <activity android:name=".MarcaSubTags" />
    <activity android:name=".MarcaConfiguracaoDePerfil" />
    <activity android:name=".MarcaServicoSubCategoriaLayout" />
    <activity android:name=".MarcaServicoSubCategorias" />
</application>
```

**MY build.gradle (Project: NanoDigital)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71"
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**MY build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.service.NanoDigital"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
  }

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0 alpha2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:wear:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.7.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.nikolajakshic:instagramauth:1.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

**EDIT WHEN I PUT "tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory and on application" GIVES ME ANOTHER ERROR**

```
Manifest Sources 

app main manifest (this file)
Other Manifest Files (Included in merge, but did not contribute any elements) animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 manifest, appcompat:1.0.0 manifest, appcompat-v7:28.0.0 manifest, asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0 manifest, support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0 manifest, aws-android-sdk-auth-core:2.6.31 manifest, aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.31 manifest, cardview-v7:28.0.0 manifest, constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2 manifest, coordinatorlayout:1.0.0 manifest, support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0 manifest, core:1.0.0 manifest, core-runtime:2.0.0 manifest, cursoradapter:1.0.0 manifest, support:cursoradapter:28.0.0 manifest, support:customtabs:28.0.0 manifest, customview:1.0.0 manifest, support:customview:28.0.0 manifest, support:design:28.0.0 manifest, documentfile:1.0.0 manifest, support:documentfile:28.0.0 manifest, drawerlayout:1.0.0 manifest, support:drawerlayout:28.0.0 manifest, lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1 manifest, firebase-analytics:16.0.3 manifest, firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1 manifest, firebase-auth:16.0.3 manifest, firebase-auth-interop:16.0.0 manifest, firebase-common:16.0.2 manifest, firebase-core:16.0.3 manifest, firebase-database:16.0.2 manifest, firebase-database-collection:15.0.1 manifest, firebase-firestore:17.1.0 manifest, firebase-iid:17.0.2 manifest, firebase-iid-interop:16.0.0 manifest, firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.0 manifest, firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.1 manifest, firebase-messaging:17.3.2 manifest, firebase-storage:16.0.2 manifest, firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0 manifest, firebase-ui-common:4.2.0 manifest, firebase-ui-database:4.2.0 manifest, firebase-ui-firestore:4.2.0 manifest, firebase-ui-storage:4.2.0 manifest, fragment:1.0.0 manifest, glide:gifdecoder:4.8.0 manifest, glide:4.8.0 manifest, gridlayout-v7:28.0.0 manifest, nikolajakshic:instagramauth:1.1.0 manifest, interpolator:1.0.0 manifest, support:interpolator:28.0.0 manifest, legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 manifest, legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 manifest, materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2 manifest, lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0 manifest, lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0 manifest, lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0 manifest, lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0 manifest, lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1 manifest, livedata-core:1.1.1 manifest, loader:1.0.0 manifest, support:loader:28.0.0 manifest, localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0 manifest, support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0 manifest, play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1 manifest, play-services-auth:16.0.0 manifest, play-services-auth-api-phone:15.0.1 manifest, play-services-auth-base:15.1.0 manifest, play-services-base:15.0.1 manifest, play-services-basement:15.0.1 manifest, play-services-flags:15.0.1 manifest, play-services-measurement-api:16.0.1 manifest, play-services-measurement-base:16.0.2 manifest, play-services-stats:15.0.1 manifest, play-services-tasks:15.0.1 manifest, print:1.0.0 manifest, support:print:28.0.0 manifest, protolite-well-known-types:16.0.0 manifest, recyclerview-v7:28.0.0 manifest, core:runtime:1.1.1 manifest, lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1 manifest, slidingpanelayout:1.0.0 manifest, support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0 manifest, support-compat:28.0.0 manifest, support-core-ui:28.0.0 manifest, support-core-utils:28.0.0 manifest, support-fragment:28.0.0 manifest, support-media-compat:28.0.0 manifest, support-v4:28.0.0 manifest, support-vector-drawable:28.0.0 manifest, swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0 manifest, support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0 manifest, support:transition:28.0.0 manifest, vectordrawable:1.0.0 manifest, vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0 manifest, versionedparcelable:1.0.0 manifest, support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0 manifest, lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1 manifest, viewpager:1.0.0 manifest, support:viewpager:28.0.0 manifest, support:wear:28.0.0 manifest  Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:15 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 14 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)
```

**AND ANOTHER ERROR**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:59)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:130)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:210)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:540)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:173)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
... 108 more
```

Answer (score 7):

I have solved this problem.

Add these two lines to your `gradle.properties` file:

`android.useAndroidX=true`

`android.enableJetifier=true`

for more help: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 1):

Add this `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to you manifest's `Application` tag :

```
<application
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    ...
```

EDIT: You might also need to add

`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools` to the `manifest` tag

Comment: I facing another error = Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
    Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:15 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 14 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

Comment: i just looked at your build.gradle, looks like you mentioned `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` twice. Remove one of them

Comment: I just deleted but. I faced another error LOL WTF is going on with my project. LOOK MY EDIT

Comment: remove the `replace` part that you added in your application tag

Comment: same error = Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-78:19 to override.

Comment: @PinhaDooido I have the problem now, have you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If it says 
**Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs**
that means you need to open your manifest and to hit the tab above. It will bring you to a window where you can see the reason of build fail . Scroll the right part of that window. Then you can continue stackoverflowing.

Answer (score 0):

In gradle.properties add these 2 lines:-

```
    android.useAndroidX=true
    android.enableJetifier=true
```